# Debugging error ' pointer from integer without a cast '

Tags: c

While running the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void insert(int len,int ele,int pos, int ar[]){
    int x= pos,i;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        ar[pos+1]=ar[pos];
        pos++;
    }
    ar[x]=ele;
    for (i=0;i<len+1;i++){
        printf("%d",ar[i]);
    }


}
int main(){
    int len,pos,ele,i;
    int ar[len];
    printf("Enter length of array");
    scanf("%d",&len);
    for( i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("Enter element ");
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter element to insert ");
    scanf("%d",&ele);
    printf("Enter position  ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    insert(len,ele,pos,ar[len]);
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:26:5: warning: passing argument 3 of 'insert' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     insert(ele,pos,ar[5]);
     ^
test.c:2:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
 void insert(int ele,int pos, int ar[5]){
```

I am a beginner in programming who's learning C for the Uni course. I am trying to make sense of the error but I am unable to do. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not use a cast**

Comment: `insert()` needs a pointer as its 4th argument... you are passing an invalid element of the array. `insert(len,ele,pos,ar[len]); /* ar[len] is invalid, it's an int (if it was valid), not a pointer */`

Comment: @pmg So what should I change in this code?

Comment: You should read the value of `len` before using it uninitialized as the size of an array. You should simply pass `ar` to the function. You'll still have a problem since insert seems to think there is extra space at the end of the array and there is not.

Comment: As RetiredNinja says, to solve your immediate problem and pass a pointer (to the 1st element of the array) use just the array identifier `ar` on its own. This is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. There may be other problems with the code, I didn't check.

Answer (score 1):

The `insert` function expects the `ar` argument to be a pointer to an `int`. By passing an element of an `int` array, you have passed just an `int`.

This is a warning rather than an error because a pointer is a numeric type, so you *can* do this, but you shouldn't. You've just passed something that isn't a valid pointer. Your function then tries to derefence that *(not really a)* pointer with:

```
ar[pos + 1] = ar[pos];
```

Remember that `ar[pos]` is equivalent to `*(ar + pos)`.

This invokes the dreaded undefined behavior.

You should just be passing `ar` to `insert`. The array decays to a pointer to its first element.

```
insert(len, ele, pos, ar);
```

Note also that C (and many other languages) has arrays with indexes  starting at `0`, so for an array `arr` with length `len`, the last valid element in the array is at `arr[len-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     int ar[len];
> ```

Is a way to *declare* an array of `int`.  The name it designates for the array is `ar`, so when you want to *refer to* that array itself, just `ar` is what you use.

If, in an expression, you then say `ar[len]`, that designates an `int` at index `len` in array `ar` -- which in this case happens to be out of bounds for the array, so the code is doubly wrong.

Thus, here:

> ```
>     insert(len,ele,pos,ar[len]);
> ```

you mean

```
    insert(len,ele,pos,ar);
```

, or, equivalently,

```
    insert(len,ele,pos,&ar[0]);
```